# Cambiar el 1 de un MAX CASE por una imagen en php

Tags: php, sql

A ver si me logro explicar amigos, tengo esta consulta que he logrado ejecutar correctamente gracias a ustedes, estoy trabajando en postgreSQL y php, y así queda construida mi tabla para mostrarlo en la página en php

```
<div id="tabs-8" class='panel'>
    select distinct no, FOLIO_FAMILIA, ID_MUNINICPIO, ID_LOCALIDAD,
                PERROS, CERDOS, VACAS, LOROS
                from (
                select distinct row_number() OVER (order by e.FOLIO_FAMILIA, 
                e.ID_MUNICIPIO, e.ID_LOCALIDAD) as No, 
                e.FOLIO_FAMILIA,  e.ID_MUNICIPIO, e.ID_LOCALIDAD,
                MAX( case when id_caso=1 then 1 else 0 end) as PERROS,
                MAX( case when id_caso=2 then 1 else 0 end) as CERDOS,
                MAX( case when id_caso=3 then 1 else 0 end) as VACAS,
                MAX( case when id_caso=4 then 1 else 0 end) as LOROS
                from encuesta e , bienes b, zona z
                where e.FOLIO_FAMILIA = b.FOLIO_FAMILIA 
                and e.FOLIO_FAMILIA = z.FOLIO    
                and e.ID_MUNICIPIO = '12-15'
                and id_caso in (1,2,3,4) and z.id_zona='12-15-1'        
                group by e.FOLIO_FAMILIA, e.ID_MUNICIPIO, e.ID_LOCALIDAD
                order by e.FOLIO_FAMILIA, e.ID_MUNICIPIO, e.ID_LOCALIDAD) as t1;
$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
            $rows = pg_num_rows ($result);
            $i = pg_num_fields($result);


            echo "<table class='table table-fixed' border=1> <tr>";
            for($j=0; $j<$i; $j++){
                    $fieldname=pg_field_name($result, $j);
                    echo "<th>".strtoupper($fieldname)."</th>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";

            while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<tr>";
                    for($j=0; $j<$i; $j++){
                        if ($line[$j] <> "") {
                            echo "<td align='left'>$line[$j]</td>";
                        }
                        else{
                            echo"<td align='left'>&nbsp;</td>"; 
                        }
                    }   
                        echo "</tr>";   
                } 
                echo "</table>";
        ?>
    </div>
```

La función primordial de esta tabla es que el usuario pueda ver un análisis general en cuanto a los animales, el resultado actual se visualiza así en mi página
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que yo quiero lograr es sustituir ese uno (1) por una imágen o ícono, es decir, que tenga una apariencia mas o menos así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo lograr eso, o tienen alguna idea de qué tipo de código php se utiliza para lograrlo,

gracias!

Comment: deberías poner el código donde armas la tabla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si es como supongo, que llenas tu tabla en el `while`, podrías hacer fácilmente lo que quieres usando un Operador ternario.

Veamos primero el código:

```
if ($line[$j] <> "") {
                            $column=$line[$j];
                            $html=($column==1) ? '<img src="/punto_azul.png">' : $column;
                            echo "<td align='left'>$html</td>";
                        }
```

Ahora lo explicamos:

- `$column=$line[$j];` almacena cada valor del bucle para someterlo posteriormente a evaluación
- Este es el operador ternario: `($column==1) ? '<img src="punto_azul.png">' : $column;` Lo que hace es evaluar si `$column` es igual a `1`. Si lo es almacenará en la variable `$html` una ruta válida de la imagen. **Muy importante:** En el ejemplo he supuesto que tienes una imagen llamada `punto_azul.png` y que la misma se encuentra en la misma carpeta donde está el presente archivo PHP. Si no, después de `src` **debe ponerse la ruta correcta de la imagen para que funcione**.
- Finalmente, con `echo "<td align='left'>$html</td>"` imprimimos el valor resultante de la cada evaluación, que se encontrará siempre en `$html`.

**P.D.**: Para presentar el punto azul, se pueden usar otras técnicas. Por ejemplo si en tu proyecto dispones de librerías como [`FontAwesome`](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/) puedes aprovecharlas para este tipo de cosas. De ese modo te evitas tener que manipular imágenes. En ese caso, la línea de la imagen quedaría así:

```
$html=($column==1) ? '<i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>' : $column;
```

Esto imprimiría [un círculo](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/circle/) de `fontawesome`. Podrías cambiarle el tamaño fácilmente, o el color, mediante css.

Comment: Para prueba coloqué una imagen, llamada punto en la carpeta img de mi proyecto, pero me sigue imprimiendo el 1, esta así mi while ahora           while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    for($j=0; $j<$i; $j++){
      if ($line[$j] <> "") {
       $column=$line[$j];
                            $html=($column==1) ? '<img src="./img/punto.png">' : $column; 
        echo "<td align='left'>$line[$j]</td>";
      }
      else{
        echo"<td align='left'>&nbsp;</td>"; 
      }
    } 
    echo "</tr>"; 
   } 
   echo "</table>";

Comment: @Indiradev26 te falta un pequeño detalle, **cambiar** el `echo`, aquí: `echo "<td align='left'>$line[$j]</td>";` por lo siguiente: **`echo "<td align='left'>$html</td>";`**

Comment: :D mil gracias, ya quedo y le di diseño con las fuentes de bootstrap, gracias hermano de verdad!